# place textView and editText on the same line in android app

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i want to place a TextView and EditText on the same line in the following main.xml. How do i do that?

```
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtTotalAmt" android:id="@+id/txtTotalAmt" ></TextView>
<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TotalAmt" android:maxLength="6" android:text="0.00" android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"></EditText>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i believe a surrounding linearLayout with orientation=horizontal is what your after. you could also try using a Tablelayout + Tablerow

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="56px" 
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="@string/txtTotalAmt" 
                android:id="@+id/txtTotalAmt" >
            </TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/TotalAmt" 
                android:maxLength="6" 
                android:text="0.00" 
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That does put the two elements in the same line. Thank you. Now if i wanted another TextView in the next line, should put it in another linearlayout?

Comment: Thanks but i dont want to use tables.

Comment: yes you could have a `<linearLayout android:orientation="vertical"><other text box here></linearLayout>` around the horizontal linearLayout. But if you creating more complex rows( i assume this is a list row?) then eventually its good to use table rows. One issue is not to get carried away with sub layouts or tables because it can use up resources (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html)

Comment: Having multiple layouts within a linearlayout works for me. I dont want to use tables. No, its not a list row. Just sections in the display. I agree. too many sub layouts is not a good idea. Mine is a small app that i'm doing for learning purpose. its good to know that i dont have to use tablelayout.

Comment: Good to hear :) I'm quite new to android myself so its good to share on here what we learn. I was just pointing out to keep embedded tables/layouts in mind for future stuff